# PDO request within a class

Tags: php, class, pdo

Here is my class :

```
class ProfileLink {

    function profileLink(PDO $pdo, $string, $i=0)
    {
        if ($i!=0) {
            $link = $string . '-' . $i;
        } else {
            $link = $string;
        }
        $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT link FROM users WHERE link = ?');
        $req->execute(array($link));
        $nb = $req->rowCount();
        $req->closeCursor();
        if ($nb > 0) {
            $i++;
            return profileLink($pdo, $string, $i);
        } else {
            return $link;
        }
    }

}
```

When I call the profileLink function from the class, it doesn't work, but if I call it outside the class, everything is ok. It might be a problem with the PDO, what do you think ?

```
require_once ('lib/profileLink.class.php');
$profileLink = new ProfileLink();
$link = $profileLink->profileLink($pdo, $string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the instance of PDO as a class property so that it can be easily accessed within the class.  Note that my example uses slightly different syntax (modern PHP).

```
class ProfileLink {

    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;  
    }

    public function profileLink($string, $i=0)
    {
        if ($i!=0) {
            $link = $string . '-' . $i;
        } else {
            $link = $string;
        }
        $req = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT link FROM users WHERE link = ?');
        $req->execute(array($link));
        $nb = $req->rowCount();
        $req->closeCursor();
        if ($nb > 0) {
            $i++;
            return profileLink($string, $i);
        } else {
            return $link;
        }
    }

}
$profileLink = new ProfileLink($pdo);
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, the way you stored the PDO is perfect in my case !

Comment: You could also create a wrapper around PDO. A good example would be ExtendedPDO through Aura\SQL. Link [here.](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Sql)

Answer (score 0):

2 Things:

here

```
 return profileLink($pdo, $string, $i);
```

you are missing a `$this`, because it's no regular function but a class method:

```
 return $this->profileLink($pdo, $string, $i);
```

And second, your method has the same name as the class (except of the first capital letter), and thus seems to be interpreted as constructor. I have just tested this:

```
class Test {
    function test() {
        echo "test";
    }
}
$t = new Test();
```

And it outputs `"test"`.

So you should rename your method to `getLink` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks Mario, I'll try to follow theses rules. But profileLink($pdo, $string, $i); or $this->profileLink($pdo, $string, $i); returns the same result for me.

Comment: Really? I get a Fatal error. I assume your code never reaches the function call.